# SQL - Multiple data output when running query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to build a report that shows the name of people under their Title, which is the column.

I am new to SQL so I have created the following query, the data is across 2 tables so there is a join, the ID column contains the Persons ID number so I need the report to match the ID with the person and then display it as their name.

Each job has a contract code so I want to show the contract code and then the people linked with that contract code.

```
Select distinct isnull(h.ContractCode, '0000') as "Contract Code", 
(Select distinct K.name 
from WF_HSReport
where h.SiteManager=k.id) as "Site Manager",
(Select distinct K.name 
from WF_HSReport
where h.ContractManager=k.ID) as "Contract Manager",
(Select distinct K.name 
WF_HSReport
where h.SHEQAdvisor=k.ID) as "SHEQ Advisor",
(Select distinct K.name 
from WF_HSReport
where h.HSDirector=k.ID) as "HS Director",
(Select distinct K.name 
from WF_HSReport
where h.SHEQManager=k.id) as "SHEQ Manager",
(Select distinct K.name 
from WF_HSReport
where h.ContractsDirector=k.id) as "ContractsDirector"
FROM WF_HSReport h
JOIN KUAF k
ON h.SiteManager=k.ID 
or h.ContractManager=k.ID 
or h.SHEQAdvisor=k.ID 
or h.HSDirector=k.ID
or h.SHEQManager=k.ID
or h.ContractsDirector=k.ID
where h.VersionNum = -1
```

So I am aware this might not be the best way to write the query but it is giving me a result. such as this:

[Data Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTMRx.png)

As you can see there is multiple lines for each job and some jobs change the person that has a job signed to them, this shouldn't matter about the people as the last line determines the current version so should cancel out the older names.

What I need to do is have one line per Contract Code showing the people currently associated with the job ?

Cheers.

PS, My brain is a little fried so apologies if I left stuff out.

**UPdate**

The first suggestion from Jeremy worked however the result is still showing multiple Contract Codes so my Where clause doesn't seem to be implementing.

[Multiple ContractCode Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFxzZ.png)

I'm sure it is something I am either overlooking or just something I don't know yet.

Comment: I would suggest that you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: it sounds alot like you need expanding columnds based on the results, when it should really be increased rows for extra records. Is there a reason you cant run each one as a seperate query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can solve this issue.

One method is to remove your join statement and only use the sub-select queries, but you would need to restructure your sub-select queries to select from KUAF instead of WF_HSReport.

```
Select distinct isnull(h.ContractCode, '0000') [Contract Code]

,(SELECT TOP 1 k.name FROM KUAF k WHERE k.ID = h.SiteManager) [Site Manager]
,(SELECT TOP 1 k.name FROM KUAF k WHERE k.ID = h.ContractManager) [Contract Manager]
,(SELECT TOP 1 k.name FROM KUAF k WHERE k.ID = h.SHEQAdvisor) [SHEQ Advisor]
,(SELECT TOP 1 k.name FROM KUAF k WHERE k.ID = h.HSDirector) [HS Director]
,(SELECT TOP 1 k.name FROM KUAF k WHERE k.ID = h.SHEQManager) [SHEQ Manager]
,(SELECT TOP 1 k.name FROM KUAF k WHERE k.ID = h.ContractsDirector) [ContractsDirector]

FROM WF_HSReport h
where h.VersionNum = -1
```

The other method would be to do a Left outer join on the KUAF table for each personnel type and use an alias.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(h.ContractCode,'0000') [Contract Code]
,sm.name [Site Manager]
,cm.name [Contract Manager]
,sa.name [SHEQ Advisor]
,hd.name [HS Director]
,sm.name [SHEQ Manager]
,cd.name [Contract Director]
FROM WF_HSReports h
LEFT OUTER JOIN KUAF sm ON h.SiteManager = sm.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN KUAF cm ON h.ContractManager = cm.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN KUAF sa ON h.SHEQAdvisor = sa.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN KUAF hd ON h.HSDirector = hd.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN KUAF sm ON h.SHEQManager = sm.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN KUAF cd ON h.ContractDirector = cd.ID
WHERE h.VersionNum = -1
```

This is assuming that ID is in fact a unique key. If it's not unique, then be sure to add whatever qualifier you would need to make sure you are only returning the correct personnel type. i.e.

```
#.ID = h.SHEQManager AND #.Type = 'Manager'
```

Add to WHERE Clause:

```
WHERE h.VersionNum = -1 AND h.ContractCode IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: That first one worked a treat, It condensed down the results for me and although there is duplicate ContractCode entries as I can't figure out how to implement a Group By clause using ContractCode I am pretty happy with that help, cheers.

Comment: No the Group By still doesn't work I'm afraid, it gives the error 'WF_HSReport.SiteManager' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause, the same one I was getting prior to your suggestion.

Comment: Got it, I will remove it from the answer.  The Distinct clause should be taking care of any duplicates in the first place. So Group By really wouldn't be a good solution for this anyways.

Comment: The duplicate contract codes could very well be coming from NULL records. Since your ISNULL statement is returning '0000' if the value is NULL. Try adding to your where clause. Unless your getting duplicates from the other numbers.

Comment: I would imagine the duplicates are coming from User input rather than an issue with the SQL as you say.
I guess the guys inputting the data need to be a bit better at it.
Thanks a million for your help.